# Filling Excel Workbook from sqlserver HRESULT: 0x800401A8 error

Tags: sql, vb.net, multithreading, excel

I am trying to fill an excel sheet from SQL Server database and getting a message with code

> HRESULT: 0x800401A8

Please assist me.

```
   Dim file As String = "C:\Techform.xlsx"


    Dim xlApp_2 As New Excel.Application
    xlApp_2.Visible = False
    xlApp_2.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
    oBook = xlApp_2.Workbooks.Open(file)

    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet


    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
    objConnection.Open()
    adapter_view.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand()
    adapter_view.SelectCommand.Connection = objConnection
    adapter_view.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TECHNICAL_AMS_CALC_GARGANTUA "
    adapter_view.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    adapter_view.Fill(dataset, "GARGANTUA_AVERAGE_Data")
    dataTable_CALC = dataset.Tables("GARGANTUA_AVERAGE_Data")
    adapter_view.Dispose()
    For h As Integer = 0 To dataTable_CALC.Rows.Count - 1


        SoG_AVG = dataTable_CALC.Rows(h).Item("VPM_SPEED_THROUGH_WATER_AVG")
        oSheet.Range("E3").Value = dataTable_CALC.Rows(h).Item("VPM_SPEED_THROUGH_WATER_AVG")
        oSheet.Range("F3").Value = dataTable_CALC.Rows(h).Item("VPM_SPEED_THROUGH_WATER_MAX")



        oBook.SaveAs(file + " " + dataTable_CALC.Rows(h).Item("ACTION_DATE") + ".xlsx", CreateBackup:=False)
        oBook.Close()
        xlApp_2.Quit()
    Next
```

Comment: Try to move the Nextabove oBook.SaveAs

Comment: I cant undertasnt what you mean with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
    Dim file As String = "C:\Techform.xlsx"

    Dim xlApp_2 As New Excel.Application
    xlApp_2.Visible = False
    xlApp_2.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim oBook As Excel.Workbook
    oBook = xlApp_2.Workbooks.Open(file)

    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet


    oSheet = oBook.Worksheets(1)
    objConnection.Open()
    adapter_view.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand()
    adapter_view.SelectCommand.Connection = objConnection
    adapter_view.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TECHNICAL_AMS_CALC_GARGANTUA "
    adapter_view.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    adapter_view.Fill(dataset, "GARGANTUA_AVERAGE_Data")
    dataTable_CALC = dataset.Tables("GARGANTUA_AVERAGE_Data")
    adapter_view.Dispose()
    For h As Integer = 0 To dataTable_CALC.Rows.Count - 1

        SoG_AVG = dataTable_CALC.Rows(h).Item("VPM_SPEED_THROUGH_WATER_AVG")
        oSheet.Range("E3").Value = dataTable_CALC.Rows(h).Item("VPM_SPEED_THROUGH_WATER_AVG")
        oSheet.Range("F3").Value = dataTable_CALC.Rows(h).Item("VPM_SPEED_THROUGH_WATER_MAX")

    Next
    oBook.SaveAs(file + " " + dataTable_CALC.Rows(h).Item("ACTION_DATE") + ".xlsx", CreateBackup:=False)
    oBook.Close()
    xlApp_2.Quit()
```